# mod_rewrite - Fixing absolute paths

Tags: linux, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a site in a staging environment that sits on an IP in a virtual directory, example: `http://0.0.0.0/~drupal`.  The problem is, I've set up all of the image, css, and js URIs using absolute pathing, example: `/path-to-image/img.jpg`.

Since the site is sitting in a directory though, `/path-to-image/img.jpg` points to `http://0.0.0.0/path-to-image/img.jpg`

instead of `http://0.0.0.0/~drupal/path-to-image/img.jpg`.

I believe the solution lies in utilizing mod_rewrite, but have been unable to implement a successful solution.

Sidenote: I think it's also possible to modify my host file on my local computer when viewing the site to get a desired effect.  However, this won't be an option since there will be many parties viewing the site as it undergoes changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try adding this to the **DOCUMENT ROOT**, meaning the directory that `http://0.0.0.0/` accesses:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/~drupal%{REQUEST_URI} -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /~drupal/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Thanks, let me give that a try.

Comment: Thought about this a little more, won't this prevent me from using other virtual directories for other websites on the same server?

Comment: @Russell it will, so you either need to move your assets out of the ~drupal directory and into your document root or change your links. However, the rewrite only happens if the request actually exists in the `druppal directory

Comment: Alright, thanks for all of the input.  I decided that I will just have to use dedicated IPs for each site with no virtualization. I'll go ahead and mark your answer as accepted though.